# Flutter build web vs Flutter build web --release

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

Can someone explain me what's the difference if I put --release or if I don't? Which mode does it choose if don't write the --release argument?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

**In debug mode**, the app is set up for debugging on the physical device, emulator, or simulator.

**Debug mode for mobile apps mean that:**

- Assertions are enabled.
- Service extensions are enabled.
- Compilation is optimized for fast development and run cycles (but not
  for execution speed, binary size, or deployment).
- Debugging is enabled, and tools supporting source level debugging
  (such as DevTools) can connect to the process.

**Debug mode for a web app means that:**

- The build is not minified and tree shaking has not been performed.
- The app is compiled with the dartdevc compiler for easier debugging.

**Use release mode for deploying the app,** when you want maximum optimization and minimal footprint size. For mobile, release mode (which is not supported on the simulator or emulator), means that:

- Assertions are disabled.
- Debugging information is stripped out.
- Debugging is disabled.
- Compilation is optimized for fast startup, fast execution, and small
  package sizes.
- Service extensions are disabled.

Release mode for a web app means that:

- The build is minified and tree shaking has been performed.
- The app is    compiled with the dart2js compiler for best
  performance.

more infor [Flutter's build modes](https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/build-modes)

Comment: So, "flutter build web"  builds in debug mode?

Comment: Yes, flutter build Is a debug mode.

Comment: "flutter build web" generates release build (https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/web/building#build)

Answer (score -1):

I think this question has the answer you need, it runs but without debug features.

[Flutter debug vs release builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55871206/flutter-debug-vs-release-builds)